# Django custom 404 page not working as intended

Tags: html, django, apache2

I am trying to implement a custom 404 page into my Django app. I am hosting the site with apache. The HTML page 404.html is:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
 <title>404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body>
 This page does not exist
</body>
</html>
```

My views.py has this view for the handler:

```
def handle404(request, exception):
     return render(request, 'mainapp/404.html', status=404)
```

My urls.py has this:

```
from django.conf.urls import handler404
handler404 = views.handle404
```

All the other things on my site work, so what could be causing this to fail?

Answer (score 0):

So, the actual problem was a typo in

```
def handle404(request, exception):
 return render(request, 'mainapp/404.html', status=404)
```

Where I spelled `exception` as `exeption`.